# Hide parent element not containing specific text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, show-hide

I am trying to hide parent elements using ID of child as selector; if they do not contain specific text. In this case `*`. Must be this way and have to use jQuery.

So far I have this:

HTML

```
<div>
    <label>
        First name <font color="red">*</font>
        <input type="text" id="guest_first_name">
    </label>
</div>

</br>

<div>
    <label>
        Last name 
        <input type="text" id="guest_last_name">
    </label>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

    let checkthis = $("#guest_first_name, #guest_last_name").parent();  
    var removewithout = "*";
    checkthis.not(removewithout).hide();

 })

</script>
```

Struggling to check elements that do not contain text and then hide. Trying to hide `<label>` with text `Last name` as it does not contain `*`. Hope this is clear. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.not()` method accepts selectors, jQuery objects, and functions.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  let checkthis = $("#guest_first_name, #guest_last_name").parent();
  var removewithout = /\*/;
  checkthis.not((i, e) => removewithout.test(e.innerHTML)).hide();

})
```

**Reference:**

- [jQuery .not( function )](https://api.jquery.com/not/#not-function)

Comment: yeah nice. I have not used his method before and will need to do more work on familiarising myself with objects. Thanks for pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

The **.not()** method in jquery & .not selector in javascript only accepts the objects, selectors and functions as parameters.
But you are passing a character for that:

Here is the more **brief code** that can help you:

HTML:

```
  <div>
     <label>
        First name <font color="red">*</font>
        <input type="text" id="guest_first_name">
    </label>
  </div>

 </br>

 <div>
    <label>
        Last name 
        <input type="text" id="guest_last_name">
    </label>
 </div>
```

JQUERY:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    let checkthis = $("input['text']").parent();
    var removewithout = /\*/;
    checkthis.not((i, e) => removewithout.test(e.innerHTML)).hide();
});
```

```html
<div>
    <label>
        First name <font color="red">*</font>
        <input type="text" id="guest_first_name">
    </label>
</div>

<br>

<div>
    <label>
        Last name 
        <input type="text" id="guest_last_name">
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I can see that in the example I gave this is the brief method. However, in the larger project I'm working on there are other input fields I do not want hidden and so decided to select using set of ID's. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @WheresMyElement 
Let's rock with code 
You are welcome